# Sudo user only using default root password for ssh access

Tags: linux, ssh

Hello I am just starting with linux and I am going through the hardening process, I have set up a password for my sudo account and changed the root default password.

The problem is that when I access ssh with my sudo account, the only password that accepts is the default root password.

I tried changing the password after accessing with the default root one but it tells me that the new password is the current password.

How can I fix this? :(

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Hi, welcome to [so]. Unfortunately your first question here is off-topic, as it is not programming related. You may want to try one of our sister-sites, e.g. [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: What do you mean by "`sudo` account"? `sudo` is just a tool for running a command as a different user (`root`, by default). If a password is required by the `sudo` configuration, it's just your login password.

Comment: Hi, I meant the user we create in linux to avoid using root user, sorry if I did not explain myself well. Seems that I posted this in the wrong forum lol. Thanks anyway for responding the first answer helped me :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a new account with admin privileges and set your password to that account. By default root is meant not to have a password to prevent you logging in as root.

Comment: Please don't answer obviously off-topic questions, suggest where to ask those instead. In this case, for example, [unix.se] or [su].